# Browning kentia leaves

Tags: houseplants

I recently purchased a 5 ft kentia and placed it next to a patio door, but out of direct sunlight. I water it sparingly when the topsoil has dried out and it is well drained. The only thing I have done is given it Baby Bio feed.I have looked for insect infestation and found none. It seems to be turning brown and dying quite quickly now.

Comment: a pitcture please!

Answer (score 1):

Phil, there was a [previous question regarding Kentia](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/38277/kentia-palm-leaves-turn-brown) with nice photos and a careful answer by @kevinsky; if you have trouble uploading photos of your situation then compare with these and report back.

Generally speaking if the dying leaves are just the older leaves with new bright leaves coming along to replace them then your palm is probably just going through an adjustment phase and will grow out of any problems you think you see. If the whole plant is affected then look to the quality of the water you are using, boost the humidity if it is low, and if possible examine the roots for new healthy growth. Sometimes if you tilt the pot on its side you can pull the plant out enough to see what is happening in the root ball.